# C# Winform PostMessage doesn't work specific process

Tags: winforms, keyboard, focus

My Program's PostMessage confirmed that key inputs are sent without focus.

However, certain processes cannot be sent, but when focus on, the key input starts.

Is this not possible for security reasons of that process?

```
            while (true)
            {
                Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(_processName);

                foreach (Process proc in processes)
                    PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, (int)Keys.A, 0);

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
```

I expecting 'Key Input without focus'.
Some process works nice.
But certain process doesn't work.